# Getting an iterator on a (private) inherited vector<string>

Tags: c++, string, vector

I've defined a private inheritance of vector on my custom class, and I want to get an iterator on it. But I am getting a conversion error.

Here is my solutions.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#ifndef SOLUTIONS_H_
#define SOLUTIONS_H_

class Solutions : private std::vector<std::string>
{
public:
    using std::vector<std::string>::begin;
    using std::vector<std::string>::end;
    using std::vector<std::string>::push_back;
    void Show() const;
};

#endif
```

Here is my solutions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "solutions.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;


void Solutions::Show() const
{   
    cout << "Solutions : " << endl;
    if ( ! vector<string>::empty() )
    {
        for (vector<string>::iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
        {
            cout << *it << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my test_solutions.cpp

```
#include "solutions.h"

int main()
{
    Solutions resultat;

    resultat.Show();

    resultat.push_back("10 + 7 = 17");
    resultat.push_back("3 /  3 = 1");
    resultat.push_back("17 - 1 = 16");

    resultat.Show();

    resultat.push_back("AA * BB = CC");
    resultat.push_back("CC - DD = EE");
    resultat.push_back("AA * EE = FF");

    resultat.Show();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the command i used on terminal (compiler Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) :

```
g++ solutions.h solutions.cpp test_solutions.cpp -o test_solutions
```

Here is the error given by the compiler :

```
solutions.cpp: In member function ‘void Solutions::Show() const’:
solutions.cpp:12:44: erreur: conversion from ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >}’ requested
```

How can I fix the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to extend `std::vector` rather than having a private vector member and wrapping the methods you care about in your class?

Comment: No, I wanted to test my new C++ knowledge : this is why i favored private inheritance over composition. But sure, with composition, all can be easier.

Comment: Is one of those files named `test_solutions.cpp`?  Because right now you have two `solutions.cpp`.

Comment: Please don't use `using` in headers as it will cause a wide variety of headaches for clients of your code in the future.

Comment: @MarkB Ok, I did not know about this convention. I will pay attention to it now.

Comment: @MarkB Removed avoidable usings from the header file (the others are part of my public interface, so I must keep them).

Comment: C++ containers are not designed to be inherited from.  There can be good reasons to ignore that design issue, but they are few and far between.

Comment: @Yakk Ok, I didn't know. So next times, for STL classes, I will prefer composition over private inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is actually pretty good.  You need to use a `const_iterator` here:

```
    for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
//                       ^^^^^
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
```

The reason is that you're inside a `const` member function, so you can't call the non-`const` version of `begin()` and `end()`.

Or just use `auto`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer : the error message was too verbose for me to understand it. Apologizes. As auto is C++11 feature (I will keep Ansi 98 for a while), I won't use it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`

```
 for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```